# decision paranoia

Tags: interviewing

I finished my fourth / last round of interview for an internship and was told from round 1 that there would be four interviews given that I do well in each round.

After the last interview, I followed up to my HR rep who then told me that they I was selected to be set up with another dev for another interview. I was puzzled because they told me there would be four, but I set up another time anyways. I was then emailed about 20 minutes later that they forgot I just finished my fourth one (they thought I just finished my third one), and that I am done with the process and should just wait for a decision the next week.

Summary:

HR forgot that I finished four rounds and instead thought I only finished three and tried setting me up for a fourth after hearing back from my fourth interviewer.

Am I in a good position? I'm asking because I figured the only reason why I would try to be set up with another developer after the 4th round is because my last (4th) interviewer thought I should move on to the next round. I know this seems really petty, but is there any other reason why what happened might have happened?

Comment: Someone just messed up.

Comment: There's nothing to see here.  Someone in HR messed up, you're now just waiting for a decision.  There's no hidden agenda, just an HR mixup.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure whether your "move on" means "move on to the next interview" or "move on to another opportunity."  However, based on your "given that I do well in each round" HR wouldn't have thought you were up for round 4 if your last interviewer didn't like you.  Sit tight and wait for the decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** Take it all at face value.

This just reads as a pure HR mixup, nothing more, nothing less.  There's nothing to see here, just someone made a mistake then corrected it when it came to light.

I wouldn't read anything further into it.  Just wait for the outcome and with luck you should know in a few days time.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are neither in a better or worth position than just after finishing the 4th round.

There is no secret 5th round.

It would be a bad policy and unnecessarily dishonest towards you. Furthermore, with 4 rounds of interviews they should have enough information to choose the best suited candidate, especially for an internship.

Error happens, even during recruitment.

Comment: I think you might have misinterpreted the question; I know there's no secret 5th round, but I'm saying that if they really thought I just finished the third round and not the fourth and I didn't do well, then they would not have wanted to set me up for the fourth round. As in, my last interviewer must've thought I did well enough to move on to tell my HR rep to set me up for another round?

Comment: How many round of interview have you finished? I suggest you modify the question as it appears you finished the 4 round of interviews already.

Comment: My first sentence states that I finished four. I'll add a little summary to make it more clear, thanks

Comment: "thought I just finished the third round and not the fourth and I didn't do well" Does it means you went to the fourth round but did not finish it?

Comment: No, I finished all four. HR rep forgot that this interview was my fourth, and thought it was my third. They tried setting me up for a fourth after hearing back from my fourth interviewer (I think this means I did well on the fourth) and soon realized their mistake, telling me that I am actually done with the process and should just wait now

Comment: In other words, this was strictly a process glitch. As such all it tells you if that they haven't said no yet. But it does tell you that. Continue interviewing in case they don't make an offer, but they are at least interested.

Answer (score 1):

HR made a blunder, thats all.

What that means for your chances is uncertain, and also irrelevant.

Just wait it out.